Python tkinter Class Object - How to change button text when button is defined in one Class, and its command function is defined outside
I have defined Class GUI which creates a button with a YES text on it.
I do not understand how I should pass the command to it when the function is defined outside of the Class.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pdb
from tkinter import *

def changeButtonText():
    input_bt['text'] = 'No'
    input_bt['relief'] = 'sunken'

class GUI: 
    def __init__(self, master) -> None: 
        root.title('Learning TKinter')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        color = '#aeb3b0'
        root.geometry("100x100")
        root.configure(bg=color)
        # Instantiating master i.e toplevel Widget 
        self.master = master 
        # Creating Button
        input_bt = Button(self.master, text='Yes',width=8,command="") # how to add command 'changeButtonText' here?
        input_bt.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)
        input_bt['relief'] = 'raised'

root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop() # original working place for root

Basically I want to press the Button so that it goes from Yes to No; and relief raised to sunken.
And i need to do this via Class/Object since I am trying to learn about these.
I am new to Python Class Object material and would appreciate help to get me going on this.
Thank you
I tried using 'command = self.changeButtonText':
input_bt = Button(self.master, text='Yes',width=8,command=self.changeButtonText) # how to add command 'changeButtonText' here?

But it is giving me this error:
AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'changeButtonText'

Try using a lambda function to call it.
First add the argument "input_bt" to "changeButtonText" like so:
def changeButtonText(input_bt):
    input_bt['text'] = 'No'
    input_bt['relief'] = 'sunken'

Then change the line:
input_bt = Button(self.master, text='Yes',width=8,command="") # how to add command 'changeButtonText' here?

To:
input_bt = Button(self.master, text='Yes',width=8,command=lambda: changeButtonText(input_bt))


You should put the def changeButtonText() inside the class GUI. This works for me:
class GUI: 
def __init__(self, master) -> None: 
    root.title('Learning TKinter')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    color = '#aeb3b0'
    root.geometry("100x100")
    root.configure(bg=color)
    # Instantiating master i.e toplevel Widget 
    self.master = master 
    # Creating Button
    self.input_bt = Button(self.master, text='Yes',width=8,command=self.changeButtonText)
    self.input_bt.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)
    self.input_bt['relief'] = 'raised'

def changeButtonText(self):
    input_bt['text'] = 'No'
    input_bt['relief'] = 'sunken'


I get error:NameError: name 'input_bt' is not defined

Fix the indentation. BTW, you need to use self.input_bt instead inside changeButtonText().

Make the changeButtonText a method within the GUI class. Like this:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class GUI: 
    def __init__(self, master) -> None: 
        root.title('Learning TKinter')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        color = '#aeb3b0'
        root.geometry("100x100")
        root.configure(bg=color)
        # Instantiating master i.e toplevel Widget 
        self.master = master 
        # Creating Button
        self.input_bt = Button(self.master, text='Yes',width=8,command=self.changeButtonText) 
        self.input_bt.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)
        self.input_bt['relief'] = 'raised'
    def changeButtonText(self):
        self.input_bt['text'] = 'No'
        self.input_bt['relief'] = 'sunken'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop() 

